# How does MATLAB scale coefficients to scalogram for the Continuous Wavelet Transform function?

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I am trying to compare wavelet coefficients over time and between signals. Toward this end, `MATLAB`'s `cwt` function. The output `[coefs sgram] = cwt(foo)` gives me the wavelet coefficients and the scalogram coefficients representative of said coefficients in terms of their total contribution to signal energy.

What I need to be sure of is that I understand how this performed "under the hood" so that these comparisons are valid. I test this using reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/cwt.html

My concern is regarding the coloration options. In this example, we use 'scal'. The documentation does not tell me exactly how it works. I have attempted to use other coloration options with my specified sampling rate and it appears that the scaling is not constant. I would like to know how it is calculated.

```
load vonkoch
vonkoch=vonkoch(1:510); 
len = length(vonkoch);
cw1 = cwt(vonkoch,1:32,'sym2','plot'); 
title('Continuous Transform, absolute coefficients.') 
ylabel('Scale')
[cw1,sc] = cwt(vonkoch,1:32,'sym2','scal');
title('Scalogram') 
ylabel('Scale')
```

If I extract the maximum values for `cw1` and `sc` using `[ms is] = max(abs(cw1(:)))` and `[mc ic] = max(sc(:))` (absolute because coefficients are sometimes negative) I note that they occupy the same index and the values are

```
mc = 0.0084
ms = 0.1313
```

Whose ratio `ms/mc = 15.6310`. But, testing on two other values, `cw1(4,4)` and `sc(4,4)` I cannot reproduce this ratio. How does `'scal'` work? If possible, links further describing the other coloration modes and how they scale coefficients into a scalogram representation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Scale from `cwt`(This version of cwt is no longer recommended. Use the updated `cwt` instead.) have following equation "under the hood":

```
WSCALOGRAM Scalogram for continuous wavelet transform.
%   SC = WSCALOGRAM(TYPEPLOT,COEFS) computes the scalogram 
%   SC (percentage of energy for each coefficient). COEFS is
%   the matrix of continuous wavelet coefficients (see CWT).
%   The scalogram is obtained by computing:
%       S = abs(coefs.*coefs); SC = 100*S./sum(S(:))
```